# Is the expression 'decltype(MyTag::non_static_m.test + 1)' syntactically valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

The question is the commented lines' in the code below:

```
struct MemberType
{
    int test;
};

struct MyTag
{
    MemberType non_static_m;// Note that it's NOT defined with 'static'.
};

int main(void)
{
    typedef decltype(MyTag::non_static_m) TestType_Good;// Well-formed in C++11.
    typedef decltype(MyTag::non_static_m.test) TestType_1;// Is it right or wrong?
    typedef decltype(MyTag::non_static_m.test + 1) TestType_2;// Is it right or wrong?

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the member in 'MyTag' is a non-static field.
I would be grateful if relevant clauses in the ISO standard documents were listed.

Comment: All are correct. Good syntax or bad, depends on the situation and other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid. In unevaluated operands (decltype, sizeof among others) you can name nonstatic datamembers without an object expression, within arbitrary subexpressions. Note that that this does not apply to nonstatic member functions, but only to data members.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **decltype** on any valid C++ expression, therefore your 3 statements are correct (it has nothing to do with static or non static modifiers).

Section 7.1.6.2 of the standard says

> The type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as follows:

- if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5),  decltype(e)
  is the type of the entity named by e . If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
- otherwise, if e is an xvalue, decltype(e) is T&& , where T is the type of e ;
- otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T& , where T is the type of e ;
- otherwise, decltype(e) is the type of e.

For standard references, see [stroustrup FAQ here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#decltype)

Comment: The expressions in the question aren't normally valid C++ expressions, you cannot access non-static data members without an instance of the class type defining the member. There's a special exception that makes it okay in unevaluated contexts, so your conclusion is correct, but your answer misses the point as to why your conclusion is correct.

Comment: I'm still reading the two pdf documents the linkage provided. I'l be back later. @hvd: Actually I've read the 7.1.6.2 and several other clauses about the decltype before posting this question since I found that there SEEMS not enough excuses to let the kind of expressions as ones written in the source being compiled according only those clauses.

Comment: @unituniverse That's because it's not in 7.1.6.2 directly :) 7.1.6.2 says "The operand of the decltype specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5)." and 5 (specifically 5.1.1p12) says it's allowed in unevaluated operands. It's not a special exception for `decltype`, but it's also allowed in e.g. `sizeof`.